# Partial view not rendering MVC razor

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

It's my first time using partial views and I am unable to get the actual partialview. The ajax function gets called, the controller gets hit, and an alert in the ajax call shows me that the partialview is there. But, with errors written to the console (or alert) my div remains just as empty.
My application is an MVC4 app, but I am pretty sure I've just done a silly mistake somewhere and its not MVC's fault :)

AFter a few hours of googling, I would really be happy anybody can help me get this working, and all tips/comments on code/ajax i greatly appreciated!

```
public PartialViewResult Groups()
{
        var person = _userRepository.GetCurrentUser();
        var connections = (from c in person.Person1 select c).ToList();
        var groups = _context.Groups.Where(g => g.GroupId == 1);

        var all = new GroupViewModel()
                      {
                          Connections = connections,
                          GroupDetailses = (from g in groups
                                            select
                                                new GroupDetails
                                                    {
                                                        Name = g.Name,
                                                        StartDate = g.StartDate,
                                                        StartedById = g.StartedById,
                                                    })

                      };
        return PartialView("Groups",all);
}
```

My PartialView

```
@model Mvc4m.Models.GroupViewModel

<h2>Groups</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<h3>Create new Group</h3>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="group">Groupname: </label>
    <input id="group" />
    <button onclick="addGroup()">Add</button>
</div>

@foreach (var item in Model.GroupDetailses)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Name)<text> : </text>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)
}
<script>
    function addGroup() {
        $.get(
                "/Profile/AddGroup",
                {
                    Name: $("#group").val()
                });
        location.reload();
    };
</script>
```

My Ajax call on Profile/Index

```
@model Mvc4m.Models.ProfileView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div id="test" style="background-color:Aqua; width:200px; height:100px"></div>

<button onclick="load()"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function load() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Profile/Groups',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#test').html(response);
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status + " : " + error);
        }

    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: seriously, I cant get the formatting rigth on this site :( I intended the code part by four spaces, how come it turned out like this, again?

Comment: what is the error in console ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code works, a restart of visual studio did the trick! How I hate VS sometimes...

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: 2010 Ultimate, it has been 'breaking up' with me a few times a day latetly :/

Comment: Ugh.  That's no fun.  I've been using the Beta version of Visual Studio 11, and it seems really stable, so you might want to give it a try.  By the way, what's up with your website (perfectdiet.com)?  I just get a "Forbidden" error.

Comment: @EthanBrown Oh, the redrect is down, having issues with the web-hotel :/  moved the site to irisclasson.com/blog a couple of months ago. I've been meaning to give VS11 a go, I guess it is time. Had to forceclose VS 10 times yesterday as it wouldnt let me adit my cs files :/